# OAuth2 with cloud services on devices with limited input capabilities

Tags: oauth-2.0, google-oauth, dropbox-api, box, onedrive

I'm new to the OAuth Authentication process so be gentle:

**Goal**: To create an embedded application on a device that will integrate with Google Drive, Dropbox, One Drive, Box to retrieve & store documents. This can be easily accomplished with OAuth2 authenticaiton.

**Problem**: The devices have limited input capabilities (and no browser) that prohibit users from being directly redirected, for them to input username/pass on the device.

**Research**: I've noticed looking through the documentation for these APIs that Google provides something called [OAuth2 For Devices](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2ForDevices) which allows the device to request a "User Code" when they first attempt to use the application on the device. The user can then go to a computer, navigate to a specific URL, and input that code to authorize the device to access their account. This circumvents to need for user input, or a browser at all, on the physical device.

**Question**: Do Dropbox, Box, OneDrive, or any others allow for this type of functionality, or anything comparable? As far as I can tell Google is the only one supporting this type of workflow.

Comment: The Dropbox API doesn't offer anything quite like this, but I'll be sure to pass this along as a feature request.

Comment: Did you see also that OAuth2 For Devices only supports a limited set of scopes: https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2ForDevices#allowedscopes. GDrive is not available.

Comment: @While-E I am currently in a similar situation - have you made any progress on this investigation?

Answer (score 0):

Recently i've researched the same question and i've found out that while Google Drive Api supports OAuth2 flow for limited devices, it supports [a very limited set of scopes](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2/limited-input-device#allowedscopes). It means that Drive api for limited devices can offer only application data synchronization (files uploaded by app), because it won't find any files created by the user (outside of application, i.e. from web) even in a dedicated application folder. *(assuming that user understands that application owns that folder and everything placed there ideally should be accessible by that)*

By 2022, i've found the most promising api is from [Koofr](https://app.koofr.net/developers) which doesn't have such limitation for devices and bundles multiple cloud services into one package.

Their documentation doesn't mention support for limited devices, yet it's fully working and can be found in their [online HTTP api test suite](https://app.koofr.net/developers/api#/).